# Winform lost all elements c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I had a button1 with onclick already created something like

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
...code ...
}
```

I change the button name to "reloadConf" in the design view, after that I just change the name in the .cs file, after that I select in the properties of the design view the name of the new function, I mean I change the event Clic from "Button1_Click" to "ReloadConf_Click" from the list of functions.

After that I lost all the elements in the form and I just have an empty form. but in the designer is everything including the elements (buttons, labels...)

**how can I recover the elements in the form?**

hope someone can help me.

Comment: Really confused what you mean by "I lost all the elements in the form and I just have an empty form" if you don't mean in the designer.  Do you mean that your code won't compile when it tries to access the controls by name?  Do you mean that your code compiles fine but none of the controls are visible when you run your program?

Comment: Post your VS version. Close your form and don't save it. Open and try again by using VS options - rename.

Comment: That's correct, the code compile ok, but in the visual design the components like buttons are not present anymore even the form change his size to the original when you start a project, but keps the elements that don't need visual space like timers. unfortunately I save close and open again.

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.2.3

Comment: If you're using source control, just reset your local repository to undo any local changes not pushed yet. If you're not using source control, now is a good time to start!

Comment: No, I don't have source control, but thanks.

Comment: Is it just the designer UI (that's been rather flakey for a while in VS), i.e. the controls are there at run-time? (and thus also in the .designer partial class)

Comment: If I run the project, it show the empty form. All the elements exist in the Form1.Designer.cs.

Comment: Huh that's... not what I expected! If you add a new form with some controls, that one works fine yeah?

Comment: yes, if I add elements to the current form there is no problem. i have not tried with another one.

Comment: Try deleting the bin and obj folders, then right-clicking the solution and doing a Clean then a Rebuild, ...perhaps restart VS for good measure too. Sounds like some caching issue.

Comment: Found the problem!
In the Form1.Designer.cs all the elements that are after the button that I change the name, all the elements are not attached to form1, lost many properties, that exist before, and position is point(0,0).

So basically is a mess. Will use a copy from 5 days ago, but I still will need to add the element that was not 5 days ago.

Comment: PS: I use this page web to compare both files designer.cs, https://www.diffchecker.com/diff

Comment: Hi Rafael Alfredo Zelaya Amaya, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. 
It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: Thank you. The system tell me that I have to wait 4 more hours to mark as accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem! In the Form1.Designer.cs all the elements that are after the button that I change the name, all the elements are not attached to form1, lost many properties, that exist before, and position is point(0,0). So basically is a mess. Will use a copy from 5 days ago, but I still will need to add the element that was not 5 days ago.

PS: I use this page web to compare both files designer.cs, diffchecker.com/diff